# Best practice to store relations in Java GAE with datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I wonder what is best practice to store relations in GAE with datastore.

If I have User and UserItem. How should I store reference to User inside UserItem?

Should I store:

- hashed key value (eg: *ag1taWNlM2hlZGdlaG9ncg8LEglMZXZlbFVzZXIYSAw*)
- unhashed key value (eg: *User("1")* )
- any other suggestion?

Comment: What language? In python, you'd generally use a ReferenceProperty.

Comment: In Java. It seems like ReferenceProperty is only in Python.

Comment: which datastore api are you using?

Comment: I use default GAE datastore API with Entities. (not JDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you would use the [Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key) property to store a reference to another datastore object.

Comment: So if I want to get related object I should do like this or there is a shortcut? 
user = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService().get(userItem.getProperty("userKey"));

Comment: @knagode - yep, that should do it.